# An error in parsing a document

Tags: java, dom, document

I have an error while converting an **InputStream** into a **Document**, i'm using the **DocumentBuilder** and i made imports the following way but i have a **incompatible types** error.

**the code :**

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document; ////
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder; ////
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory; ////

public static Document parse(InputStream is) { // converting the resulted InputStream to a document

Document doc = null ;    
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory;
DocumentBuilder builder;

try {
domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setValidating(false);
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse(is);  // I have the error here
} catch (Exception ex) {
System.err.println("unable to load XML: " + ex);
}

return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your import of com.sun.xml.internal.trw2.Document into org.w3c.dom.Document.

Comment: org.w3c.dom.Document is XML.  From the javadoc: "The Document interface represents the entire HTML or XML document."